# Google Maps API with PHP to find distance between two locations

Tags: php, google-maps

On my current project, which is a delivery system, I have a list of available delivery drivers, which is shown on an orders page. But what I need is to show the distance each delivery is from the customers address. The distance should be shown next to each driver's name. Anyone have any clues on how I would go about this?

Comment: what exactly do u want?? is it you want function to compute distance between 2 location whose co ordinates are available or u want to get also their geolocation co ordinates and then find distance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you want driving distance and not straight line distance, you can use the Directions web service:
You need to make an http or https request from your PHP script and the parse the JSON or XML response.

Documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

For example: 
Boston,MA to Concord,MA via Charlestown,MA and Lexington,MA (JSON)
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Boston,MA&destination=Concord,MA&waypoints=Charlestown,MA|Lexington,MA&sensor=false

Boston,MA to Concord,MA via Charlestown,MA and Lexington,MA (XML)
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Boston,MA&destination=Concord,MA&waypoints=Charlestown,MA|Lexington,MA&sensor=false

Note that there are usage limits.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily calculates the distance between two address using Google Maps API and PHP.

```
$addressFrom = 'Insert from address';
$addressTo = 'Insert to address';
$distance = getDistance($addressFrom, $addressTo, "K");
echo $distance;
```

You can get the getDistance() function codes from here - http://www.codexworld.com/distance-between-two-addresses-google-maps-api-php/

Comment: JoyGuru, I've been trying to get this working, does this work for you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143960/php-distance-between-2-addresses-with-google-maps - just posted a question, maybe you could provide some insight? I seem to be doing everything properly? Just thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 1):

**this will out seconds between 2 location**

```
$origin =urlencode('Optus Sydney International Airport, Airport Drive, Mascot NSW 2020, Australia');
$destination = urlencode('Sydney NSW, Australia');
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=$origin&destinations=$destination&key=your_key";
$data = @file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($data,true);
echo $data['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['value'];
```