# PHP: Distance between 2 addresses with Google Maps?

Tags: php, google-maps

I'm trying to get the distance between 2 locations through Google Maps API using the below PHP script, which apparently works (their hosted test url works, added below), but when I use the code they provide on my own server it doesn't seem to do anything... PHP is working just fine by the way, and it doesn't seem to be doing anything funny that would require me turning something on in my ini file.

I'm not sure what the issue is... been at this all day.

Any ideas? Maybe it is my .ini?

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I'm using a shared host, but that shouldn't make a difference. It should technically work as is, any way that is why I'm here - I need some insight.

---

Website with source code:
http://www.codexworld.com/distance-between-two-addresses-google-maps-api-php/#comment-24117

Their live demo: http://demos.codexworld.com/distance-between-two-addresses-google-maps-api-php/

My full test code:

```
<?php
/**
*
* Author: CodexWorld
* Function Name: getDistance()
* $addressFrom => From address.
* $addressTo => To address.
* $unit => Unit type.
*
**/

    function getDistance($addressFrom, $addressTo, $unit){
        //Change address format
        $formattedAddrFrom = str_replace(' ','+',$addressFrom);
        $formattedAddrTo = str_replace(' ','+',$addressTo);

        //Send request and receive json data
        $geocodeFrom = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$formattedAddrFrom.'&sensor=false');
        $outputFrom = json_decode($geocodeFrom);
        $geocodeTo = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$formattedAddrTo.'&sensor=false');
        $outputTo = json_decode($geocodeTo);

        //Get latitude and longitude from geo data
        $latitudeFrom = $outputFrom->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $longitudeFrom = $outputFrom->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
        $latitudeTo = $outputTo->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $longitudeTo = $outputTo->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

        //Calculate distance from latitude and longitude
        $theta = $longitudeFrom - $longitudeTo;
        $dist = sin(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * sin(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) +  cos(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * cos(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
        $dist = acos($dist);
        $dist = rad2deg($dist);
        $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        $unit = strtoupper($unit);
        if ($unit == "K") {
            return ($miles * 1.609344).' km';
        } else if ($unit == "N") {
            return ($miles * 0.8684).' nm';
        } else {
            return $miles.' mi';
        }
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['addrFrom']) && !empty($_POST['addrTo'])) { 
        $addressFrom = htmlspecialchars($_POST['addrFrom']);
        $addressTo = htmlspecialchars($_POST['addrTo']);
        $distance = getDistance($addressFrom, $addressTo, "K");
        $success = true;
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <p class="distance"><span>Distance:<?php if ($success == true) { echo ' ' . $distance; } ?></span> </p>
        <p><label>Address From</label><input type="text" name="addrFrom" value=""></p>
        <p><label>Address To</label><input type="text" name="addrTo" value=""></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate Distance"></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: start echoing some variables

Comment: `$success` is undefined

Comment: @Dagon Thanks for commenting, sorry I actually just forgot to put that back in, I had that in as a test on my end to see if the basics worked... Just put it back. I've echoed $addressFrom and $addressTwo, and $distance, from that I know that $formattedAddrFrom and $formattedAddrTo have to work... Haven't checked $geocodeFrom and that set of variables though. I'll echo a few variables and report what I find.

Comment: tested locally works fine, hard coded addresses. if you want to dump this http://ideone.com/ypdYAjin to a file by itself and test that:

Comment: sorry its here: http://ideone.com/ypdYAj

Comment: Hmm, what's strange is on my host it doesn't seem to even go through the function: http://mrobertsdesign.ca/fountain/get_distance.php I've added all the functions as echoes below and it doesn't do anything at all... hmm

Comment: thanks by the way, that's a good tool to have

Comment: is full error checking\display on

Comment: No, I will do that right now though. Also, this question doesn't even seen worthy of stack overflow so once we do a couple more things I suppose I'll delete it. I really appreciate your time though.

Comment: Done, posted the same code you provided. http://mrobertsdesign.ca/fountain/get_distance.php

Comment: the api is simply not returning anything hence the notices - have you been hitting it a lot? you may have reached the number of requests allowed. to check you need to get the http headers:

Comment: Not really, been trying to get it to work all day, but it's been like that from the start?

Comment: You lost me at http headers, how would I go about that?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php - would this be something of what I'm looking for?

Comment: try the updated version: http://ideone.com/ypdYAj

Comment: Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.0 200 OK [1] => Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 [2] => Date: Tue, 22 Mar 2016 00:55:43 GMT [3] => Pragma: no-cache [4] => Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT [5] => Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate [6] => Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * [7] => Server: mafe [8] => X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block [9] => X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN [10] => Accept-Ranges: none [11] => Vary: Accept-Language,Accept-Encoding )

Comment: well i m confused, let me test a few things

Comment: I appreciate it, I suppose you didn't see anything funny in that array? I'm not sure what to look for to be honest with you... but since it didn't work from the beginning I didn't think it had timedout or hit the limit.

Comment: 200 tells me its not blocking your ip due to to many requests.. whcih was my guess at the time

Comment: `var_dump($geocodeFrom );` just after the line $geocodeFrom... Lets be real sure we know hwat google is sending us back :)

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: geocodeFrom in /hermes/bosnaweb11a/b549/ipg.mrobertsonlinecom/fountain/get_distance.php on line 11 NULL Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.0 200 OK [1] => Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 [2] => Date: Tue, 22 Mar 2016 01:15:52 GMT [3] => Pragma: no-cache [4] => Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT [5] => Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate [6] => Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * [7] => Server: mafe [8] => X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block [9] => X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN [10] => Accept-Ranges: none [11] => Vary: Accept-Language,Accept-Encoding )

Comment: you put it in the wrong place nad you can remove that other debugging code updated here: http://ideone.com/ypdYAj

Comment: Done and done, awwh man I've been down voted lol - I understand though.

Comment: string(245) "{ "error_message" : "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. We recommend registering for a key at the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/", "results" : [], "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" } "

Comment: BINGO **error_message" : "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.**

Comment: Yup, you're right... as we're doing this I've been working on getting that key... so let's see if the key makes it work...

Comment: now wasent my first comment to echo all the variables ;)

Comment: Haha... yes. Good point. I've learned quite a bit through this. http://mrobertsdesign.ca/fountain/get_distance_2.php - now it says I need to be using SSL, so it looks like this is a no go - because I don't plan on paying for SSL just to make this work.

Comment: you dont have to pay for anything if the srever is set up correctly just use https instead of http

Comment: Hmm, https://mrobertsdesign.ca/fountain/get_distance_2.php doesn't change anything, it still doesn't see it as being https

Comment: you change the API requests to https.  `file_get_contents('https://maps....`

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try This - slightly modified your way of doing it..:

```
<?php
/**
* Author: CodexWorld
* Function Name: getDistance()
* $addressFrom => From address.
* $addressTo => To address.
* $unit => Unit type.
*
**/

    function getDistance($addressFrom, $addressTo, $unit){
        //Change address format
        $formattedAddrFrom = str_replace(' ','+',$addressFrom);
        $formattedAddrTo = str_replace(' ','+',$addressTo);

        //Send request and receive json data
        $geocodeFrom = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$formattedAddrFrom.'&sensor=false');
        $outputFrom = json_decode($geocodeFrom);
        $geocodeTo = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$formattedAddrTo.'&sensor=false');
        $outputTo = json_decode($geocodeTo);

        //Get latitude and longitude from geo data
        $latitudeFrom = $outputFrom->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $longitudeFrom = $outputFrom->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
        $latitudeTo = $outputTo->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $longitudeTo = $outputTo->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

        //Calculate distance from latitude and longitude
        $theta = $longitudeFrom - $longitudeTo;
        $dist = sin(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * sin(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) +  cos(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * cos(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
        $dist = acos($dist);
        $dist = rad2deg($dist);
        $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        $unit = strtoupper($unit);
        if ($unit == "K") {
            return ($miles * 1.609344).' km';
        } else if ($unit == "N") {
            return ($miles * 0.8684).' nm';
        } else {
            return $miles.' mi';
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $addressFrom = htmlspecialchars($_POST['addrFrom']);
        $addressTo = htmlspecialchars($_POST['addrTo']);
        $distance = getDistance($addressFrom, $addressTo, "K");
        echo $distance;    
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <p><label>Address From</label><input type="text" name="addrFrom" value=""></p>
        <p><label>Address To</label><input type="text" name="addrTo" value=""></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate Distance"></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```