# Php get distance between two custom point google map with Live map display

Tags: php, dictionary

How to  get distance between two custom (customer can enter From , to paths) points google map with Live map with marker

and i want diplay it with live map  with 2 markers

Comment: I want Php code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps API with PHP to find distance between two locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328625/google-maps-api-with-php-to-find-distance-between-two-locations)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the formula to calculate distance between two points:

```
dlon = lon2 - lon1
dlat = lat2 - lat1 
a = (sin(dlat/2))^2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * (sin(dlon/2))^2 
c = 2 * atan2( sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a) ) 
d = R * c
```

---

```
R = the radius of the Earth
d = the distance
```